# Accidentally deleted a2ensite

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I accidentally deleted /usr/sbin/a2ensite. Any way I can restore it? Tried sudo apt-get install a2ensite but I got the error message:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package a2ensite

Tried sudo apt-get install apache2 and sudo aptitude update but no luck there either. Any ideas? Using ubuntu.

Cheers,
agsb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall apache2 apache2-common`

Comment: Hmmm, dont seem to work, I got the error:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package apache2-common is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  apache2-utils apache2.2-common
E: Package apache2-common has no installation candidate

Comment: "sudo apt-get install --reinstall apache2 apache2.2-common" worked. Thank you so much =)

Answer (score 2):

`a2ensite` as a script is contained in the `apache2.2-common` package. You can download it [here](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/amd64/apache2.2-common/download) and extract the file from the contained data archive yourself.

Edit: The Ubuntu packages can be found [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=apache2.2-common).